# I've implemented the config class for the springBoot security but I dont have the generated password in the console, how can I access the log in?

Tags: java, spring-security

I've tried to set the username and the password in the properties but didnt work
I'm trying to create a login and registration web app and I am stuck at this now
I was implementing the old way but it is deprecated so I saw this way, it is working but I cannot find a way to log in

```
package com.sample.security.config;

import com.sample.services.UserService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig  {
  private final UserService userService;
  private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http

        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/v*/registration**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
    return http.build();
  }
  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    return authProvider;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DaoAuthenticationProvider` in your example is the default, and so does not need to be published as a `@Bean` or configured manually as you have done with `.authenticationProvider(...)`. If you want to use the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` instead of `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`, you can publish it as an `@Bean` and it will be picked up automatically, like so:

```java
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Take a look at samples like our [Username and Password sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/hello-security-explicit) for a minimal example of a basic Spring Security application that you can build from.

Comment: Yes thats makes sense about the @Bean usage. I had a go through it and re studied more in depth about the spring security. I've actually sorted it. But the Bean suggestion is really what I should have done as well. The encoder it is actually a bean already in his own class . I didn't understand about the authenticationProvider(...),. Shall I just remove it from the filterChain?

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing in your snippet, I would remove it yes. The only reason to configure a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` manually in Spring Security would be if you want to expose a custom `AuthenticationManager` bean to your application (in which case you pass your `AuthenticationProvider` to the constructor of `ProviderManager`). That doesn't seem to be the case here, so manually specifying the authentication provider is redundant, as it's built internally by the framework.

Comment: I've also added a link to a sample that demonstrates this.